# Why the if statement is being executed yet the condition is false?

Tags: python, if-statement, printing, boolean

Even if the variable `bullets_fire` contains the boolean `False`, the command below is going to be executed. I also added print statement for bullets_fire nested in if statement, and it outputs **False**, why it's being executed then?

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and not bullets_fire:
        print(bullets_fire)
        bullets_fire = True
        bullets_x = player_x
        bullets_y = player_y
```

Comment: If ```bullets_fire = False``` then What is ```not bullets_fire``` ?

Comment: Hope I helped. If my answer satisfies you, please accept it as the correct answer (by pressing the V button next to it)

Comment: @Ram that not True. It worked for me before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your condition contains `not` before the boolean variable.
it will execute only if `event.key == pygame.K_SPACE` evaluates as `True` and `bullets_fire` evaluated as `False`, since `not False` is the same as `True`.

Comment: I've tried everything: `and bullets_fire is False`, `and bullets_fire` , and even nested in that if statement another if statement ```if bullets_fire is False:```, nothing works. It's not the first time when I have similar problem.

Comment: First of all, you should compare booleans using `==` and not using the `is` keyword. Secondly, what are you trying to accomplish? A condition that holds both `bullet_fire` and `event.key == pygame.K_SPACE` that would be evaluated to False when either one of them is false?

Comment: I tried the operator as you said, but it doesn't work eitherway. Code nested in if statement should run only if `bullets_fire` is false, and `event.key == pygame.K_SPACE` is true.

Comment: @SolnLase I'm not sure I understand, in your original question `bullets_fire` was **false** and `if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE` was **true**, and it went into the condition, then what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry I meant if two conditions are true. My bad

Comment: @SolnLase in that case the condition you want is `if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and bullets_fire` if there is anything wrong. if it's working you may mark my answer as helpful, if it's not, you may need to share more of your code.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work either :/, because in if statement is code which changes bullets_fire to True, and before that it's never True. I think I should change it, since the code is bad anyway. Thank you for trying to help, I was looking for explanation why if statements sometimes execute code when they're shouldn't. I can send u all my code if u need that to answer on that question or maybe you have some resources which you could link me, I would be really grateful, because I already searched the web, and didn't find anything, and I'd rather understand python.

Comment: let's make things clear :)
1. the condition you wanted to use is the one I wrote above.
2. I think you want to change `bullets_fire` to True somewhere else, and in this condition you want to change it to False, but i'd know that only if you'll add more code.
Try to edit your question and add where these variables are being defined and modified, if things are still not clear, I'll help.
3. if condition will not execute when it shouldn't, in the case you described above the values of the variables and the logic of the statement worked perfectly fine (as i described in my original answer)

Comment: Hi, sorry for reply after so long time but I abounded that project. Now I'm doing different where python also executes an if statement, even when it evaluates to false. I don't know what's wrong with this language :/ .

Comment: it easier to blame the language, but usually it's us that are wrong :)
post a question with the code and I'll try to assist

Comment: Thank you for your willing to help. I already solved that ;)